# sscanf behaviour is different

Tags: c, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   char * msg = "Internal power 10. power sufficient. total count 10";
   char * temp = "Internal power %d. power %s. total count %d";
   int v1, v2, ret;
   char str1[64];
   ret = sscanf(msg, temp, &v1, str1, &v2);

   printf("%d\n", ret);
   printf("%d %s %d ", v1, str1 , v2);

   return 0;
}
```

I want to understand why `sscanf` is failing and why it is not able to retrieve the last variable?

Comment: Because `%s` reads the `.` in `sufficient.` so the literal match of the dot in the format string fails. You'd need to use a scan set `%[^. ]` to read just `sufficient` data.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Hi, I got it, but can u pls help to know how can I achieve it with sscanf() and scan set[] and limitation is that I cannot alter the incoming message and its template.

Comment: If you can't modify the 'template' (by which I assume you mean the format string), then you are stuck. What you've got won't work; something has to change to make it work.  Maybe you need to clarify what you asked in your comment.  You've got a good answer below.

Comment: @user7375520 You have a good answer to the 2 questions _in the post_.  If you need more than either 1) append more questions to the post, (not so good an idea really) and know that comments are not sufficient.   or 2)  accept an answer and post a new question (with a reference to this one) with the additional needs well specified especially explaining _why_ "limitation is that I cannot alter the incoming message and its template".

Answer (score 7):

`%s` reads a *whitespace*-delimited string; that is, it consumes `sufficient.` by the time it gets to dot, the rest of the format, `". total count %d"` does not match the remainder `" total count 10"`.

Since you're expecting the word to be followed by `.`, you might as well use `%63[^.]` i.e. maximum 63 characters that do *not* include a dot. Or `%63[a-z]` for maximum 63 ASCII lowercase letters - specifying the width explicitly also ensures that buffer overflow can't happen:

```
char * temp = "Internal power %d. power %63[^.]. total count %d";
```

P.S. always check the return value of `*scanf` - it tells how many specifiers were matched (in this case it should be 3); however, now 2 was returned meaning that the matching failed after the second conversion.

Comment: Thanks, Can u pls also tell how to get the third variable in this case?

Comment: @user7375520 Change `power %s` to `power %63[^.]` or `power %63[a-z]` as mentioned in this answer?

Comment: limitation is that I cannot alter the incoming message and its template.

Comment: @user7375520 you cannot change *neither* the message *nor* the template? Then there is nothing you can do.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is this part of the `scanf` format string: `"power %s."`

The problem is because the `scanf` format strings are not really regular expressions or otherwise doing exact matching. When you have the `"%s"` format, then `scanf` (and its siblings) will read *everything* until the next white-space.

That means with the string you have the `"%s"` will cause your `sscanf` call to read `"sufficient."` *including* the dot. Then the call will try to match the dot which have already been read into the string and since it's not available anymore the call will fail.

You can use sets as suggested by Jonathan Leffler [in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43511349/sscanf-behaviour-is-different/43511411?noredirect=1#comment74076623_43511349). I also suggest you read e.g. [this `scanf` (and family) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) for more details.

Comment: What about scan sets?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  Limitation is that I cannot alter the incoming message and its template. and cannot use the scanf() (scan set[]) as the string is coming as part of non-STDIN

Comment: @user7375520: Note that a scan set can be used with any of the `scanf()` family of functions — it is not limited to `scanf()` alone.